# Conditional removing of duplicates pandas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to conditionally drop duplicates (using drop_duplicates specifically) in a pandas dataframe w/about 10 columns and 400,000 rows? That is, I want to keep all rows that have 2 columns meet a condition: if the combination of date (column) and store (column) # are unique, keep row, other wise, drop.

Comment: What have you tried? There are the ultimately handy `if` statements, but then yes, that can get a little bit messy. Have you check if there's a method in the documentation for this?

Comment: It's always helpful to post sample data and expected output.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to figure out how to post some sample data.

Comment: If you need code formatting, just indent by four spaces, or just copy paste it and one of us will fix it for you (especially if it's lots of data). :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `drop_duplicates` to  return dataframe with duplicate rows removed, optionally only considering certain columns

Let initial dataframe be like

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    B    10
1    A    B    20
2    A    C    20
3    C    B    20
4    A    B    20
```

If you want to take unique combinations from certain columns `'Col1', 'Col2'`

```
In [35]: df.drop_duplicates(['Col1', 'Col2'])
Out[35]:
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    B    10
2    A    C    20
3    C    B    20
```

If you want to take unique combinations of all columns

```
In [36]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[36]:
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    B    10
1    A    B    20
2    A    C    20
3    C    B    20
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you were able to clear up some confusion I had about the combos.